# Remove using statements and resolve each reference in Visual Studio 2010 (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, using, resolve

I need a way to remove ALL `using` statements from code and fully qualify the referenced lines of code. Example:

BEFORE:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace XYZ
{
    class Temp
    {
        public void IRFunction()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello!");
        }
    }
}
```

AFTER:

```
namespace XYZ
{
    class Temp
    {
        public void IRFunction()
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Hello!");
        }
    }
}
```

I am assuming that the solution would automatically answer the following question as well:
How to enumerate referenced namespaces that qualify for `using` statements and can be used to resolve references in code.

Comment: The purpose is to be able to switch between abbreviated and fully qualified code between team members. I for one have been coding with fully qualified code for 10 years now and don't have the patience to switch. Being the code reviewer, I need to create a tool to quickly switch between the two variations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to do that, but...

ReSharper can do that for you.

> Options > Code Editing > C# > Namespace Imports

Then set the "Use Fully Qualified Names" radio button.

Once that is set, you can do a "Code Cleanup" on existing code, and it will change your usings to fully qualified names.

Comment: Hmmm... What I'm looking for is to develop this tool myself rather than use ReSharper which conflicts with my existing add-ins.

Comment: Ah, sorry, your original question didn't really indicate if you wanted a tool to do it, or how to do it yourself. In my opinion, a programmer needs to code to the style that their employer dictates. Where I work, we have a shared ReSharper style that we all use, but enforcing with StyleCop is another possibility. You would be better off just forcing everyone to use your style, or you adapt to theirs. Especially once you take source control into account. You don't want everyone checking in code re-formats back and forth.